# Conditions to delete specific registry

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am trying to delete registry that has specific entry. How would I be able to delete registry when it met certain value.

**Example:**

[image]

How can I delete registry under "Products" where "ProductName" equals "VMware"

Tried:

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\*\ProductName\{VMware Tool} /f
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\ if ProductName\{VMware Tool} /f
```

Comment: You should not guess the syntax.You will have to do `reg query` first to find out the actual key name, then you can do `reg delete` to actually remove the value. Anyway, make sure that your access privileges suffice...

Comment: As you're trying to modify local machine entries, it is likely that any script/command would need to be run 'As administrator'. Also, your question is unclear, it shows us `ProductName` value data as `VMWare Tools`, but asks for `"ProductName" equals "VMware"`. Which do you need? Are you wanting to delete the key itself? or the value? or the data?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, leveraging [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from an 'As administrator' [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), *(to keep it on topic)*, is the easiest method.

This example will show you what it intends to do if you have an unknown registry KeyName under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products` with a known ValueName of `ProductName` and a known StringData matching `VMware Tools`.

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\*' -Name 'ProductName' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { If ($_.ProductName -Eq 'VMware Tools') { Remove-Item -Path $_.PSPath -Recurse -WhatIf } }"
```

*If you're happy with the output, remove  `-WhatIf` and run it again, remembering that this must be run 'As administrator'.*